# Why Velocity is not replacing values?

Tags: java, apache, velocity

My template String is as following and i want to replace the value of **$java.lang.Object.property**

```
     String tempString = "hi test message for velocity $java.lang.Object.property";
```

here i am passing context map as follow

```
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("java.lang.Object.property", "1");
    StringWriter message = new StringWriter();
    mVelocityEngine.evaluate( context, message, "LOG", tempString);
```

why velocity engine is not able to replace the value of java.lang.Object.property from the template?

Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Don't use `.` in your context names

**Long Answer:**

Velocity has special treatment for `.` and I think it's actually trying to call

```
context.get("java").getLang().getObject().getProperty()
```

I'm not 100% sure of the syntax but perhaps you could try `$['java.lang.Object.property']` or similar... probably best to check the velocity docs for how to access context variables via string/map lookup.

Another option is to add a map to the context and access via:

```
$map['java.lang.Object.property']
```

Comment: Thanks Lance for help